# how to save custom form fields data in admin in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have created three custom form fields in checkout payment section.

I have followed this link to create form fields ([How to add additional field to checkout payment (Magento 2)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130554/how-to-add-additional-field-to-checkout-payment-magento-2/)).

Now want to know how to save these fields data in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add getData method in your js file:

```
getData: function() {
            return {
                'method': "methodcode",
                'additional_data': {
                    'customfield1': $('#'+this.getCode()+'_customfield1').val(),
                    'customfield2': $('#'+this.getCode()+'_customfield2').val(),
                }
            };
        },
```

then you can get these fields in `additional data` param in your payment model:

```
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Model;

class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc
{
  public function assignData()
  {
     $post = $data->getData()['additional_data'];
     // write your custom code
}
}
```