# How to add custom fileds in Magento 2,checkout payment method

Tags: magento2, custom, payment-methods, custom-field

How to add two custom fields for all payment methods in my payment section of magento 2,Can any one help me on this?

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['payment']['children']
        ['methods']['children']['paymentAdditional'] = [
            'component' => 'uiComponent',
            'displayArea' => 'paymentAdditional',
            'children' => [
                'delivery_date' => [
                    'component' => Vendor_Module/js/view/payment/method-renderer/taxInfo-comp',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'methods',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'vendor_module/payment/taxinfo-form',
                        'options' => [],
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => 'methods.tax_code',
                    'label' => 'Tax Code',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => false, //['required-entry' => $this->_helper->getConfigIsFieldRequired()],
                    'sortOrder' => 200,
                ]
            ],
        ];
```

Comment: Please elaborate your requirements by for which purpose you need those custom fields? This thread may help you [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130554/how-to-add-additional-field-to-checkout-payment-magento-2/130565)

Comment: i want to add tax related information for all payment methods.please check this link https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sales-tax-exempt.html

Comment: Am not aware of Magento 2,but for magento 1.9 versions you can make use of these [link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/06/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page/)

Answer (score 1):

If You  want two add new custom field for all payment method in payment section of magento 2

you can overwrite **\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor**

follow this sequence

/[vendor]/[module]/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="checkout_custom_fields" type="vendor\module\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
```

vandor/module/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php

```
namespace vendor\module\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['delivery_date'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
                'options' => [],
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.your_field',
            'label' => 'field label',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 200
        ];
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

[Reference here](http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/)

Comment: The above code is for shipping method.in payment section not working.i have already tried.and the path is incorrect it should be  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor

Comment: can you please upload screen short where you need add costume field.

Comment: Please check the code in my question.

Comment: You can follow [Reference link] below at my answer. This is working .

Comment: I have already checked in payment method,not working but in shipping method its working.